# r - ggplot2 geom_tile facet_grid space

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having a problem removing the space between rows using `geom_tile` (`ggplot2`). I think it is caused by `facet_grid`.

However, using `facet_grid(~grp, drop=T, scales="free", space="free")` should work, but doesn't.

I end up getting

[image]

Any idea how I can remove the space ?

**data and codes**

```
library(dplyr) 
library(reshap2) 
library(ggplot2) 

df = as.data.frame(replicate(10, rep(sample(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')), 10) )) 
df$grp = rep(1:2,10)
df$id = 1:nrow(df)
df = df %>% melt(id.vars = c('id', 'grp'))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, id)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set3') + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  facet_grid(~grp, drop=T, scales="free", space="free") + theme_minimal()
```

Comment: The way you are specifying the `facet_grid` means both panels are _sharing_ the y-axis, so it can't be free. Use `facet_wrap` instead.

Comment: Or use `mutate(id = if_else(grp == 2, id - 1, as.double(id)))` first to equalize..

Comment: @Axeman same issue with `facet_wrap`